# Transforming nilpotency into diagonalizability

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, oa.operator-algebras, eigenvalues

We designate the $k$-th standard vector as $e_k$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

We consider the backward shift operator, denoted as $T: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$, which is defined as follows:
$Te_1=0$ and $Te_k=e_{k-1}$ where $k\geq2$. It is evident that $T$ is nilpotent, with the eigenvalue $0$ being its sole eigenvalue.

Let us define $T':\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}^n$ with $T'e_1=e_n$ and $T'e_k=Te_k$ where $k\neq1$. Then $T'$ represents the circulant matrix and so it is diagonalizable; its eigenvalues are just the set of $n^{th}$-roots of the unit in the unit circle in  $\mathbb{C}$.

> Q. Now, we turn our attention to the nilpotent transformation $S = T + T^\ell$, where $\ell \geq 2$. We establish the operator $S': \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$ as:
> $S'e_1=e_n$ and $S'e_k=Se_k$ where $k\neq1$.
> The question arises as to whether $S'$ is diagonalizable, and what is the spectrum of $S'$.

Comment: This is a basic exercise in linear algebra!

Comment: @ Paul Broussous, Based on your statement, it appears that you may have a straightforward proof or can address a theorem contributing to the solution. Otherwise, it seems you may not have read the problem accurately and have only presented an opinionated point of view.